# How to solve treesitter/highlighter: Error executing lua problem in neovim config

Tags: lua, config, neovim

I'm currently using Neovim 6.0. And I also use the following neovim-config : https://github.com/rafi/vim-config. 
After installation, I created a python program to test and a problem encountered which are as follows:

> treesitter/highlighter: Error executing lua: ...im/0.6.0/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:161: query: invalid node type at position 5622
> ~ pdb~       ⮡ Snippet [VSnip]                                                                                                                             st

Comment: Open an issue there is better than SO.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 146):

I had a similar issue. I ran `:TSUpdate` in Neovim to update Treesitter plugin and the error message disapear after relaunching.

Comment: Thanks man. I was solved this before and until now I see your answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, man. This was annoying af and I'm happy that was a simple solution.

Comment: Wow it was that simple and totally not obvious to a new neovim user

Comment: thnks a lot
that was annoying as hell

Comment: This did not solve it for me as everything was already up to date. Running `:TSInstall vim` however, as Aman suggests below, did.

Comment: This saved my life (specially eyes).
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 36):

I just solved it using `:TSInstall vim`.

Actually, run `:checkhealth` and the error in there would help in figuring out what is missing.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me! By running `:checkhealth` I was able to see the `vim` parser was not installed for Treesitter

Comment: Thank you! I was really scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 19):

Remember, in treesitter 'c', 'help', 'lua', and 'vim' are part of the core functionality of Neovim. But that means if you are seeing this error, a sure fire way to make sure they are all installed is to run:

```
:TSInstall c help lua vim
```

Comment: awesome point and comment. Very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Simplest answer and worked for me - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For me helped adding cmake to ensure_installed in the `treesitter` config section of `.config/nvim/init.lua`:

```
-- [[ Configure Treesitter ]]
-- See `:help nvim-treesitter`
require('nvim-treesitter.configs').setup {
  -- Add languages to be installed here that you want installed for treesitter
  ensure_installed = { 'c', 'cpp', 'go', 'lua', 'python', 'rust', 'typescript', 'help', 'cmake' },
```

Configuration was based on https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim

Answer (score 4):

I ran `:checkhealth` and found this:

> Legend: H[ighlight], L[ocals], F[olds], I[ndents], In[j]ections
> +) multiple parsers found, only one will be used
> x) errors found in the query, try to run :TSUpdate {lang} ~
>
> The following errors have been detected: ~
>
> - ERROR vimdoc(highlights): ...im/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259:
>   query: invalid node type at position 615 for language vimdoc
>   vimdoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:   |
>   [ERROR]:"/Users/stevencamillieri/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vimdoc/highlights.scm",
>   failed to load:
>   ...im/0.9.4/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259:
>   query: invalid node type at position 615 for language vimdoc

so I ran `:TSUpdate vimdoc` as instructed and it's fixed!

Answer (score 3):

You can also experience similar treesitter errors when installing nvim via snap. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434692/neovim-astronvim-treesitter-highlighter-error-on-comment-lines). In my case, I used the snap package because the latest neovim version on Ubuntu was significantly out of date.

If this is your case, you can install the latest version of neovim using the PPA repo.

1. First, remove the snap package:

```bash
sudo snap remove nvim
```

2. Next, install nvim from the PPA repo to get the latest version:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

**Note: This installs the latest, "unstable" version of neovim, which could have bugs. You could use the "[stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eneovim-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages)" PPA, but it is also out of date.**

See also [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#install-from-package) for other ways of installing neovim without using the native Ubuntu package manager.

Comment: the nvim snap also didn't work for me. The nvim.appimage on the github repo as well

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is similar to that answered by Oleksiy, except add `vim` to the `ensure_installed` table instead of `cmake`

Comment: Why do you think that in your case that change was needed? What effect does it have? How does that help? What might be the difference between your evnvironment and that one? Is a solution for your environment really also a solution for the question at the top of this page and its environment?

Answer (score 0):

I did `:checkhealth` and figured out that "c" and "lua" are failing for treesitter, so I changed my config as

```
-- plugins/treesitter.lua
local config = require 'nvim-treesitter.configs'
config.setup {
     ...
     ignore_install = { "c", "lua" },
     highlight = { 
        ....,
        disable = { "c", "lua" },
     },
 }
```

and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, I've removed the Markdown parser which is not installed by the `nvim-treesitter` (as it told me when I run `:TSUninstall` markdown) and that's fixed my issue, because there's no parser to run when I open markdown files now, of course this is not a solution for you if you care to have a Markdown parser.

```bash
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/nvim/parser/markdown.so
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/nvim/parser/markdown_inline.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened right after I ran `:PackerSync` command to upgrade all my nvim plugins(I use packer for managing plugins, YMMV). It seemed like `treesitter` introduced some breaking changes in the latest commits.

I ran `:checkhealth` and found errors for rust, javascript, typescript, and tsx.

I tried to re-install those parsers by running `:TSInstall rust javascript typescript tsx`, and rebooted my nvim. And it resolved the issue.