# neovim (AstroNvim) treesitter/highlighter error on comment-lines

Tags: comments, neovim, treesitter

I've just installed astronvim and have the following issue: when there is any comment in the file (python `#`, lua `--`, etc.), treesitter/highlighter displays the following error:

[image]

Some extra-information:

- I have no extra configure. Just gruvbox theme and some little plugins (with config template from astronvim docs).
- I've already tested it with pure AstroNvim - nothing changed.
- I've already checked `:TSUpdate` command. All parsers are installed and updated.
- I've already tried reinstall AstriNvim with `rm -rf` on cache, share and state of neovim.
- `:checkhealth` on treesitter shows no errors or warnings.

`nvim --version` command output:

```
NVIM v0.9.0
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -O2 -g -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wvla -Wdouble-promotion -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-common -Wno-unused-result -Wimplicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-color=always -fstack-protector-strong -DUNIT_TESTING -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include/luajit-2.1 -I/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/cmake.config -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/src -I/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include

            общесистемный файл vimrc: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
          значение $VIM по умолчанию: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

If the problem in my config, here is a link to it: https://github.com/ALittleMoron/AstroNvimConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, but I forgot to do it:

I checked neovim location with `which nvim` and realized, that my neovim was installed via snap, so I just delete it and reinstall via native package manager: `sudo pacman -S neovim` with no config resetting. All work ok now.